# How is it possible to insert a horizontal split inline element in XSL FO?

Tags: xml, layout, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I´d like to know if and how it is possible to insert a horizontal splitted (50:50) multi-line inline element into the current line (fo:block).

This picture should describe what I mean:
[image]

```
<fo:block>100mm<fo:inline>+4mm</fo:inline><fo:inline>-4mm</fo:inline>text...</fo:block>
```

As you can see the inline data "100mm would be progressed normally and then specific data "+4mm" and "-4mm" are progressed with line-height 50% and layered over another. After that the rest of the content would be added.

Is this even possible?
I use the AntennaHouse Formatter for rendering.

Comment: I wonder whether you could use https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container to achieve that with e.g. `<fo:block>100mm<fo:inline-block><fo:block>+4mm</fo:block><fo:block>-4mm</fo:bloc></fo:inline-block>text ...</fo:block>`.

Comment: this resolved my problem. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathML is your friend:

```
    <fo:block>This is my data: <fo:instream-foreign-object>
            <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
                <msubsup>
                    <mi>100mm</mi>
                    <mi>+4mm</mi>
                    <mi>-4mm</mi>
                </msubsup>
            </math>
        </fo:instream-foreign-object> and here it goes on...</fo:block>
```

[image: MathML rendered in AH Formatter GUI.]

See, e.g., https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/math-ml/presentation-markup/scripts-and-limits/subscripts-superscripts/

If you're going to be including a lot of MathML, you can put the namespace declaration for MathML on the `xsl:stylesheet` element of your XSLT so the namespace will be in scope for the whole stylesheet and will also end up on the `fo:root` of your result.

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution like Martin Honnen described does also work:

```
<fo:block start-indent="0">
    This is my data: 100mm
    <fo:inline-container baseline-shift="4.25pt">
        <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="4.25pt">+5mm</fo:block>
        <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="4.25pt">-5mm</fo:block>
    </fo:inline-container> and here it goes on...
</fo:block>
```

This gives the desired output.
[image]

Thanks for your help.